# Printing elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This code is supposed to print all the elements in an ArrayList. It should deal with an empty ArrayList by reporting it.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lab4ex1 {
    public static String prtElem(ArrayList<String> arr){
        if(arr.size() == 0) {
            return "Error: The ArrayList must have elements to print out.";
        } else {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
                return arr.get(i);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        prtElem([]);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to execute it, I get an error in line 16 whether I have elements in the array or not. Why do I get this error and how could I fix this?

Comment: `prtElem` requires a `List` argument

Comment: What's your error in line 16?

Comment: Assuming that this code actually did work, you'd only ever print out one element - you're returning `arr.get(0)`.

Comment: Just so you know, placing the `ArrayList` object in a `System.out.println` statement will print the elements contained in it. Also, you can simply use `arr.isEmpty()` instead of `arr.size() == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`prtElem` requires an `ArrayList<String>` as its argument. You are trying to call it with `prtElem([])`.

`[]` is not an `ArrayList<String>`.

Try defining an `ArrayList<String>` and passing that to your function.

Subsequently you will find (as Makoto pointed out) that this code:

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
    return arr.get(i);
}
```

just returns `arr.get(0)`, because the first time it hits the `return`, the method finishes.

Comment: How do you know that's the OP's problem?

Comment: @APerson:  It's definitely *one* of them.

Comment: @APerson It's _a_ problem.

Comment: Fair enough; those are problems.

Answer (score 0):

This will print all the elements in any `ArrayList<String>` you pass to the method:

```
public static void prtElem(ArrayList<String> arr){
    if(arr.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error: The ArrayList must have elements to print out.");
    } else {
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab4ex1 {

public static void prtElem(ArrayList<String> arr){
    if(arr.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Error: The ArrayList must have elements to print out.");
    }    
    else{
        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str);    
        }
    }    
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> arr; 
    arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three","four"));
    // arr.clear(); test Array when is empty
    prtElem(arr);         
}

}
```